# Crop textView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview, android-textattributes

I have LinearLayout with two TextView's in it - `textName` and `textPrice`. Properties of the `textName`:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and properties of the `textPrice`:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

In the case when the `textName` is long, it stretches over the entire line and closes a `textPrice`.

Here is my xml-markup:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textNameTimeHolder"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Неудержимые 3"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textPrice"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPrice"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="150 - 220 сом"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I crop a `textName` (using `singleline`), when it's too long?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `ellipsize` property in your `TextView` and its better to use a `weight` in both `TextView`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textNameTimeHolder"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Неудержимые 3"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPrice"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="150 - 220 сом"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
  android:ellipsize="end"
```

for your `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:maxEMS`(EMS is maximum space occupied a character, technically space occupied by E or M) and choose a specific length. If text is too long, it will be appended with three dots(...) automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `android:ellipsize` on your textview.